AppCommand get endless parameters
Original:
@client.tree.command()
@app_commands.describe(members='The members you want to get the joined date from; defaults to the user who uses the command')
async def joined(interaction: discord.Interaction, members: Optional[List[discord.Member]]):
    """Says when a members joined."""
    # If no member is explicitly provided then we use the command user here
    members = members or [interaction.user]
    text = ""
    for member in members:
        text += f'{member} joined {discord.utils.format_dt(member.joined_at)}\n'
    # The format_dt function formats the date time into a human readable representation in the official client
    await interaction.response.send_message(text)

members: Optional[List[discord.Member]]
I was:
/joined Member1 Member2 Member3 ...
Error:
unsupported type annotation typing.List[discord.member.Member]
File "*", line *, in 
async def joined(interaction: discord.Interaction, members: Optional[List[discord.Member]]):
TypeError: unsupported type annotation typing.List[discord.member.Member]

Discord slash commands do not support endless parameters/variadic options. The easiest solution would be to only allow a single member per command and make the user run it multiple times.
If you insist on using multiple members per command, you will need to use a workaround by creating a str argument, making the user put multiple mentions in there and then parse them. Here is an example using regular expressions:
import re

@client.tree.command()
@app_commands.describe(mentions='The members you want to get the joined date from; defaults to the user who uses the command')
async def joined(interaction: discord.Interaction, mentions: Optional[str]):
    if not mentions:
        members = [interaction.user]
    else:
        members = []
        for user_id in re.findall(r"\d{17,19}", mentions):
            member = interaction.guild.get_member(int(user_id))
            if member:
                members.append(member)

This requires Server Members privileged intent.
Reference
